# Стоит ли использовать БЭМ

Tags: бэм

Стоит ли использовать БЭМ (Блок Элемент Модификатор (Яндекс)) и, что означает независимый блок в контексте БЭМ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

БЭМ, это соглашение о наименованиях. Не MVC, и не исключает совместное использование с каким-нибудь MVC.

БЭМ помогает решить ряд определенных проблем:

- Исключить зависимые имена классов. При разработке долгоиграющих проектов или при большой команде это приводит к разъезжающимся страницам
- Существенно уменьшить усилия на изучение проекта для нового разработчика. Все части вёрстки разложены по файлам и папкам с интуитивно понятными именами
- Избавиться от копипаста в рамках страницы/сайта/портала. Блок это готовая часть вёрстки, его можно и нужно повторно использовать. Элементы и модификаторы позволяют точечно вносить изменения для каждого случая использования этого блока, избегая взаимное влияние использования модифицированных блоков на одной странице
- Избавиться от копипаста, если необходимо внести изменение в определенный компонент вёрстки. Не нужно делать правки в 100500 местах, правки вносятся в одном месте

Ценой этого является высокий порог входа к использованию БЭМ. Это принять БЭМ в сердце, разобраться с инструментами сборки, применимыми к вашему случаю, донести БЭМ до окружающих коллег. Стоит ли заплатить эту цену, решать вам.

Про АНБ в контексте БЭМ хорошо сказано здесь https://ru.bem.info/forum/issues/-46/

По сути это два правила:

1. Всем элементам внутри блока надо задать классы, т.е. не опираться в CSS на имена элементов
2. Все классы, на которые накладываются стили этого блока, должны быть уникальными, например, начинаться с имени класса корневого элемента

Answer (score 2):

Я бы очень рекомендовал БЭМ как методологию, не обязательно использовать все инструменты БЭМ как подход к разработке. Для примера: на проектах, где использовали БЭМ в коде чистота и порядок, блоки независимы, гибки (имхо модификаторы - это прекрасно) и что самое важное - они остаются блоками во всех смыслах))